# Why logger not working after greenlet_spawn calling?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a `conftest.py` for pytest where I prepare database (create it and apply alembic migrations) for test purposes:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import os
import time
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from pathlib import Path

import pytest as pytest
from alembic import command
from alembic.config import Config
from sqlalchemy import URL, text, Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncEngine, AsyncSession

from src.config import settings

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


def generate_test_database() -> str:
    timestamp = round(time.time())

    return f"test_{settings.db.database}_{timestamp}"


@asynccontextmanager
async def TestDatabase(name: str = None):
    LOGGER.info("Preparing test database")

    url = URL.create(
        drivername=settings.db.drivername,
        host=settings.db.host,
        port=settings.db.port,
        username=settings.db.username,
        password=settings.db.password,
    )
    database = name or generate_test_database()
    engine = create_async_engine(url, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")

    async with engine.connect() as conn:
        LOGGER.info(f"Creating test database {database}")
        await conn.execute(
            text(f'CREATE DATABASE "{database}" ENCODING "utf8" TEMPLATE template1')
        )
        LOGGER.info(f"Test database {database} created")

    yield url.set(database=database)

    async with engine.connect() as conn:
        LOGGER.info(f"Deleting test database {database}")
        await conn.execute(text(f'DROP DATABASE "{database}"'))
        LOGGER.info(f"Test database {database} deleted")

    await engine.dispose()


async def migrate(engine: AsyncEngine) -> None:

    def upgrade(connection: Connection):
        base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        alembic_cfg = Config(os.path.join(base_dir, "alembic.ini"))
        alembic_cfg.attributes["connection"] = connection
        command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")

    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        LOGGER.info(f"Applying migrations")
        await conn.run_sync(upgrade)
        LOGGER.info(f"Migrations were applied")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def engine():
    async with TestDatabase() as url:
        engine_ = create_async_engine(url)
        await migrate(engine_)

        LOGGER.info(f"Test database {url.database} prepared")

        yield engine_
        await engine_.dispose()


@pytest.fixture
async def session(engine):
    session_ = AsyncSession(bind=engine)
    yield session_
    await session_.close()
```

`alembic.ini`:

```
[alembic]
script_location = alembic
file_template = %%(year)d_%%(month).2d_%%(day).2d_%%(hour).2d%%(minute).2d-%%(rev)s
prepend_sys_path = .
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5433/fastapipytestsqlalchemy

[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

And `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
asyncio_mode=auto
log_cli=true
log_level=INFO
testpaths =
    tests
```

The problem with it is that logs are not printed onto console after `await conn.run_sync(upgrade)`.

The output:

```
INFO     tests.conftest:conftest.py:35 Preparing test database
INFO     tests.conftest:conftest.py:48 Creating test database test_main_1698226182
INFO     tests.conftest:conftest.py:52 Test database test_main_1698226182 created
INFO     tests.conftest:conftest.py:73 Applying migrations
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 58ca9885dc46, empty message
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 58ca9885dc46 -> 19f865f7a703, empty message
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 19f865f7a703 -> 77583f1d2868, empty message
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] BEGIN (implicit)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.middle_name, users.age 
FROM users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00024s] ()
PASSEDINFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] BEGIN (implicit; DBAPI should not BEGIN due to autocommit mode)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] DROP DATABASE "test_main_1698226182"
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00037s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK using DBAPI connection.rollback(), DBAPI should ignore due to autocommit mode
```

If I replace `LOGGER.info` to `print` statement then it works as expected.

So what's the problem with `LOGGER.info` after `await conn.run_sync(upgrade)`. Is this somehow related to greenlet_spawn? If so then how and why?